# Templates, general method returning data in derived classes

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, methods

There is the class A

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:  virtual T get() = 0;
};
```

and two derived classes B,C and get() method

```
template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
private: T b;
public:  T get() {return b;}
};

template <typename T>
struct Test
{
T data; typedef T Type;
};
```

How to design get() to be able to return a general object used as a data member? I tried to templatize the data type Test

```
template <typename Data>
class C : public B <typename Data::Type>
{
private: Data c;

public: virtual Data get() {return c;}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
C <Test<double>> *c = new C<Test<double>> ();
c->get();
}
```

but the example still does not work. The following message appears:

```
Error   1   error C2555: 'C<Data>::get':
overriding virtual function return type differs and 
is not covariant from 'B<T>::get()
```

How to fix the code? Thanks for your help...

The class hierarchy represents a very simplified example of error handling. All get() methods of the derived classes are returning error objects: variables, vectors, matrices, etc...

For example class B represents a variable, class C a matrix..

**Updated question:**

Sorry, but I am doing more things at the same time... I did not recognized

```
template <typename Data>
class C : public B <typename Data::Type>
{
```

sets the return type of A, B to double and C must return double too. The correct version is

```
template <typename Data>
class C : public A <Data>
{
private: Data c;

public: virtual Data get() {return c;}
};
```

Comment: From the code above I can't tell what you want to do. But by changing the line `virtual Data get() {return c;}` to `virtual typename Data::Type get() {return c.data;}` will make the compilation go well.

Comment: @ silvesthu: It will be used for error handling. The get() function returns object causing exceptions.

Comment: ok.I still not clear about the relation of Data and Data::Type. But at least if `class C : public B <typename Data::Type>`, the get() function should return a `Data::Type` object.

Comment: @ silvesthu. You are right, it was my mistake, sorry. And thank for your comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about what you are trying to do, but this will at least compile:

```
template <typename Data>
class C : public B <typename Data::Type>
{
    private: typename Data::Type c;

    public: virtual typename Data::Type get() {return c;}
};
```

With your code, I got the following error:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class C<Test<double> >’:
prog.cpp:30:44:   required from here
prog.cpp:25:22: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘Data C<Data>::get()
    [with Data = Test<double>]’
prog.cpp:11:12: error:   overriding ‘T B<T>::get() [with T = double]’
```

I.e. since you instantiate `B` with `Data::Type` (which is `double`), `get()` in `C` also has to return `Data::Type`, and not just `Data` (which would be `Test<double>`).